# ImportError: cannot import name '_imaging' from 'PIL' в Ubuntu

Tags: python, ubuntu, matplotlib, pil, pillow

При использовании библиотеки matplotlib в Ubuntu в Python 3 имею ошибку

```
ImportError: cannot import name '_imaging' from 'PIL' (/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/PIL/__init__.py)
```

Обновил pip, обновил обновил matplotlib, обновил Pillow. PIL обновлять не дает не из PyCharm, не из терминала. 
Подскажите, что делать? Очень нужна эта библиотека для работы.

Answer (score 1):

проблема ушла после того как я выполнил в терминале команду `pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall Pillow`